# How can I get member information by using API V3.0 from MailChimp?

Tags: curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm looking for way how to grab a specific member/user information by using his email address. Is there any documentation or example?

I'm using MailChimp API V3.0. I have tried to execute the following code but without any success:

```
curl --request GET --user 'anystring:<api_key>' --url 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members?email_address=<my_email_address>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my question. You just need to convert the email address to MD5 hash and use it for the query. Here is the correct call:

```
curl --request GET --user 'anystring:<api_key>' --url 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members/<md5(my_email_address)>'
```